# jQuery not showing "Please fill out this field"

Tags: jquery, html, validation, input

I have a form that has a few required fields. The submit button has an id of `add`.

I want to make it so if the form is valid, it will run a function called `stopNavigate()`

So in my code I have:

```
$("#add").on('click', function(){
    if($('form').first().valid()){
        stopNavigate();
    }
});
```

However when I do this, I no longer get a "Please fill out this field" tooltip on the input field. Is there a way still make it check for this?

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m1640qkL/1/) example.

The desired output is [image] for invalid input

However, when I push Submit, the jQuery Validator tries to take over with its error message. Is there a way to still have the native HTML5 validation tooltip appear?

Comment: @cale_b, yes I am talking about the native required message.

Comment: @cale_b, I have added a MCV example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are interecepting the submit button `click`, which is not permitting the browser to properly process the "required" (and other) attributes for the form fields.  In order to permit the browser to do so, you'd need to intercept the form `submit` event:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
   if($('form').first().valid()){
        stopNavigate();
    }
});
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zLnu2gj0/) demonstrating that the above change works as requested.